# How to remove multiple items from nested list in python 3?

Tags: python, list

How to remove multiple items from nested list in python 3, without using a list comprehension? And at times `Indexerror` came how to handle that?

```
split_list =[["a","b","c"],["SUB","d","e",],["f","Billing"]]
rem_word = ['SUB', 'Billing', 'Independent', 'DR']
for sub_list in split_list:
  for sub_itm in sub_list:
    if sub_itm not in rem_word:
        print(sub_itm)
```

Output Comes like this:

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e
 f
```

Expected Output:

```
split_list =[["a","b","c"],["d","e",],["f"]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use always use a list-comprehension. Get all the words to be removed in a separate list and try this :

```
>>> split_list =[["a","b","c"],["SUB","d","e",],["f","Billing"]]
>>> rem_word = ['SUB', 'Billing', 'Independent', 'DR']
>>> output = [[sub_itm for sub_itm in sub_list if sub_itm not in rem_word] for sub_list in split_list]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']]
```

If you want to do it without list comprehension, you need to declare a vacant list to append each new sub-list and also a new vacant sub-list to append all new sub-items. Check this :

```
output2 = []
for sub_list in split_list:
    new_sub_list = []
    for sub_itm in sub_list:
        if sub_itm not in rem_word:
            new_sub_list.append(sub_itm)
    output2.append(new_sub_list)
```

It outputs the same :

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f']]
```

Comment: thank you so much but i want without list comprehension

Comment: @pycoderr if you print it without appending it to other lists, it's going to print then one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use map and filter

```
split_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["SUB", "d", "e", ], ["f", "Billing"]]
remove_list = ["SUB", "Billing", "INDEPENDENT", "DR"]
split_list = list(map(lambda x: list(filter(lambda i: i not in remove_list, x)), split_list))

print(split_list)
```

Comment: thank you so much but i want without list comprehension

Comment: @pycoderr: There is no list comprehension in that code. There are other constructs, such as a map, a filter, and lambda expressions. Please clarify just what you want or do not want.

Answer (score 0):

[[x for x in z if x!='SUB'] for z in split_list]

keep in mind that it is a nested list. Treat x as the sub element and z as the element. Also keep in mind that the above code will delete all 'SUB'. just for deleting the first instance use remove.